# Extracting part of a string bounded by special symbols

Tags: bash, shell

Hello I am passing strings for example /bin/bash/Xorg.tar.gz to my  script which is

```
    for i in $*; do 
       echo "$(expr match "$i" '\.*\.')"
     done
```

I expect to return Xorg only but it returns 0,any ideas why?

Comment: As an aside: To robustly iterate over the positional parameters, use `for i in "$@"; do` instead.

Answer (score 1):

`expr match` directive attempts to match complete input not partial.

However, you can use builtin BASH regex for this:

```
[[ "$i" =~ .*/([^./]+)\. ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

This will print `Xorg` for your example argument.

Answer (score 1):

It seems weird that your string would be `/bin/bash/Xorg.tar.gz` (kinda looks like `/bin/bash` is a directory or something) but either way, you can use standard parameter expansion to get the part you want:

```
i=${i##*/}
i=${i%%.*}
```

First remove everything up to the last `/`, then remove everything from the first `.`.

Answer (score 1):

The ***immediate* fix** (leaving the loop aside):

```
$ expr '/path/to/Xorg.tar.gz' : '.*/\([^.]*\)'
Xorg
```

Note:

- `:` is needed after the input string to signal a *regex-matching* operation.

  - Note: `expr <string> : <regex>` is the POSIX-compliant syntax; *GNU* `expr` also accepts `expr match <string> <regex>`, as in your attempt.
- `expr` implicitly matches from the *start* of the string, so `.*/` must be used to match everything up to the last `/`
- `\([^.]*\)` is used to match everything up to, but not including, the first `.` of the filename component; note the `\`-escaping of the `(` and `)` (the capture group delimiters), which is needed, because `expr` only supports (the obsolescent and limited) [BRE](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03)s.
  Using a capture group ensures that the *matched string* is output, whereas by default the *count of matching chars.* is output.
- As for **the regex you used**:

  - `'\.*\.'`: `\.*` matches any (possibly empty) sequence (`*`) of *literal* `.` chars. (`\.`), implicitly at the start of the string, followed by exactly 1 literal `.` (`\.`).
    In other words: you tried to match 2 or more *consecutive* `.` chars. *at the start of the string*, which is obviously not what you intended.
  - Because your regex doesn't contain a capture group, `expr` outputs the *count of matching characters*, which in this case is `0`, since nothing matches.

---

That said, **calling an external utility in every iteration of a shell loop is inefficient**, so consider:

- [Tom Fenech's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44268267/45375), which only uses *shell parameter expansions*.
- [anubhava's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44268089/45375), which only uses Bash's built-in regex-matching operator, `=~`

---

**If you don't actually need a shell loop** and are fine with processing all paths with a **single command using external utilities**, consider this:

```
basename -a "$@" | cut -d'.' -f1
```

<sup>Note: `basename -a`, for processing *multiple* filename operands, is nonstandard, but both GNU and BSD/macOS `basename` support it.</sup>

To demonstrate it in action:

```
# Set positional parameters with `set`.
$ set -- '/path/to/Xorg.tar.gz' '/path/to/another/File.with.multiple.suffixes'
$ basename -a "$@" | cut -d'.' -f1
Xorg
File
```